# Store excel data in an array of hashes

Tags: arrays, excel, perl, hash

My table structure is :

```
Name      Address
Deepti    1325 
Cizwan     324
rikita     567
```

I have to make array like `[{Name->deepti,Address->1325},{Name->Cizwan,Address->324},{Name->Rikita,Address->567}]`

The table is in excel data, so multiple rows are there.
Thanks in Advance. I have tried something but not able to proceed.

```
for my $row_num (2..($max_rows))
{

    if(exists $workbook->{'cell'}[1][1])
        {
            #insert values in the hash 
             $id1 = $workbook->{'cell'}[1][1];
             my $val1 = $workbook->{'cell'}[1][$row_num];
            #push values in hash
            push (@{$hash1{$id1}},$val1);
    }


    if(exists $workbook->{'cell'}[2][1])
        {
            #insert values in the hash 
    $id2 = $workbook->{'cell'}[2][1];
             my $val1 = $workbook->{'cell'}[2][$row_num];
    #push values in hash
    push (@{$hash2{$id2}},$val1);
    }
```

}

```
print Dumper \%hash1;
print Dumper \%hash2;
```

Answer (score 0):

So with your structure, you're looking like an array of anonymous hashes is what you want.

This is simpler than you might think:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @rows;

chomp ( my @header = split ' ', <DATA> ); 

while ( <DATA> ) {
   chomp; 
   my %row;
   @row{@header} = split;
   push @rows, \%row; 
}

print Dumper \@rows;

__DATA__
Name      Address
Deepti    1325 
Cizwan     324
rikita     567


This outputs:

$VAR1 = [
          {
            'Address' => '1325',
            'Name' => 'Deepti'
          },
          {
            'Name' => 'Cizwan',
            'Address' => '324'
          },
          {
            'Address' => '567',
            'Name' => 'rikita'
          }
        ];
```

But fitting it into your code - you might want to:

```
push ( @rows, { Name => $id2, Address => $val } );
```

This works because putting values in `{}` like that causes it to return an anonymous hash, which you can then insert into the array.

Comment: The `chomp` calls are unnecessary.

Comment: I have to read the excel sheet,I am just a starter in perl, Is <DATA> playing the role for that.

Comment: Yes. I don't have your spreadsheet, so the `<DATA>` is pretending to be the same.

Comment: @DeeptiPandey: Welcome to the Perl community. Since you're new to Perl, I would suggest getting a copy of "Beginning Perl (by Ovid)" and Modern Perl ([Ebook is available for free](https://pragprog.com/book/swperl/modern-perl-fourth-edition)).